# Populating listboxes using Lists within a Class

Tags: c#, list, class, listbox

I am trying to turn and input into a List memeber. The inputs are recieved through a Class, appended to a string value and should then add to a list. I can't, however, get the list to work.

```
 public class Deliveries
{
    private string customername;

    public string CustName
    {
        get { return customername; }
        set { customername = value; }
    }
    private string customeraddress;

    public string CustAddress
    {
        get { return customeraddress; }
        set { customeraddress = value; }
    }
    public DateTime deliverytime;

    public DateTime DelTime
    {
        get { return deliverytime; }
        set { deliverytime = value; }
    }
    public string output;
    private void ToString()
    {
        output=deliverytime.ToString() + " " + CustName + " " + CustAddress;
    }
}
```

The list is stored in a seperate class called Lists.

```
class Lists
{
    private List<Deliveries> deliveries = new List<Deliveries>();

    public void addDelivery(Deliveries del)
    {
        deliveries.Add(del);
    }


    public List<String> listDeliveries()
    {

        List<String> listDeliveries = new List<string>();

        foreach (Deliveries del in deliveries)
        {
            String delAsString = del.ToString();
            listDeliveries.Add(delAsString);
        }
        return listDeliveries;
    }


    public Deliveries getDelivery(int index)
    {

        int count = 0;
        foreach (Deliveries del in deliveries)
        {
            if (index == count)
                return del;
            count++;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And finally, the code that should add it to the Listbox, stored in the Form Load

```
 listBox1.Items.Clear();
        List<String> delList = ListOut.listDeliveries();
        listBox1.Items.AddRange(delList.ToArray());
```

Currently, it's not adding anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Check in debugger how many items ListOut.listDeliveries(); will return on page load

Comment: Please post code where you create and populate ListOut.

Answer (score 0):

listboxes automatically display the string returned by every object through the `ToString` method. So override this method in your `Deliveries` class and delete your implementation of `ToString`.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", deliverytime, CustName, CustAddress);
}
```

Now you can add the deliveries directly to the listbox without having to convert them to a list of string first.

---

You can access a delivery in the list through its index and don't need a loop

```
public Deliveries getDelivery(int index)
{
    if (index < 0 || index >= deliveries.Count) {
        return null;
    }
    return deliveries[index];
}
```

---

Use the debugger in order to solve your problem. Set a breakpoint on the first code line of the body of the `listDeliveries` method by clicking on the gray border on the left of the line. A brown dot will appear and the code will pause on this line. By hovering with the mouse pointer over the `deliveries` variable, you will be able to inspect its content.